# Що таке пімпочка?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Натрапила на статтю [Маленькі таємниці Станиславова, які не можуть пояснити історики](http://report.if.ua/uncategorized/malenki-tayemnyci-stanyslavova-yaki-ne-mozhut-poyasnyty-istoryky/), в якій пише:

> Врешті-решт, люди відчепились від тої **пімпочки** і вона тихо-мирно мокне під дощами та відігрівається на сонці.

То що ж таке та ***пімпочка***? Шукала у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pimpochka), там такого немає.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [Словнику українського сленгу](http://www.dimaname.ru/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-17/) знаходимо:

> **ПЇМПОЧКА**, -и, ж. *Кнопочка.* Ну, і пімпочка є, якщо вже зайшла… фільтр називається:) (ЗтііНДаЗі_сНаі).

У [Лексиконі львівському](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53407/1065692.html) теж знаходимо:

> **пі́мпочка** ірон. 1. кнопка (м, ср)2. щось невелике, незначне, другорядне; дрібничка (м, ср).

Отже, зважаючи на контекст поданої вище статті можна сказати, що пімпочка – це кнопка.